# Why first line indent on UILabel dont work well with custom font?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want an multiline label that has indented first line by x points.

For this I used `NSAttributedString` and its property `firstLineHeadIndent`.

It works for most cases except if the text is just a few characters longer than one line. I figured it out that in that cases it ignores the indent. And the trailing of the label goes trough the edge of the label for exact amount that is indented.

```
let text = "Hello World! Hello World! Hee"
let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 40
attString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))
attString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: label.font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))
label.attributedText = attString
```

Here's the case when it should already break the label.
[image]

Here's the case where I make text a little bit longer and it works well:
[image]

I should note that if I use system font, it all works good. It's only in case of custom fonts. In this case I use font called Rubik. Do you have any idea how to make it work with this font.

Comment: Try label.textAlignment = .center

Comment: Didnt change anything.

Comment: Try label.lineaBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail or ByWordWrapping or any other mode

Comment: if you dont want to use `paragraphStyle.headIndent` thats ok.  You could try down size your font or You can possible try  `If` condition to change font size according to your text length....

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I am using `Rubik-Regular font` as a test font that you mentioned in your post.From your code you only setting `headIntent` to your `first line`.If you want to use `headIntent` you should be using `paragraphStyle.headIntent`.

```
    let text = "Hello World! Hello World! Hee"
    let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .left 
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 40
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 40
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    attString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))
    attString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Rubik-Regular", size: 25)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))
    label.attributedText = attString
    label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: But I dont need the indent in all lines. Only in first. The problem is just in case where I have one line of text and the trailing goes wild.